# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol byteArrayInputStream

Tags: android

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public void init(byte[] signedPDF) throws IOException {
    doc = PDDocument.load(new byteArrayInputStream(signedPDF));
}
```

Android Studio displays an error: **Cannot resolve symbol `byteArrayInputStream`.**

I tried adding the import manually:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
```

Yet, it is greyed out and still not working.

I tried restarting Andorid Studio, cleaning, building project again.

I even tried **ivalidate cahches/Restart** from the File menu.

**Nothing works.**

I read all the related posts on **stackoverflow** and nothing seems to help.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @ImAtWar for pointing out at my mistake.

Look at his answer.

It should have been `doc = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(signedPDF));`

Notice the capital B in `ByteArrayInputStream`.

I made the mistake because I'm used to using Eclipse which is not case sensitive when doing auto-complete. So, when the **ByteArrayInputStream** class didn't show up on auto-complete I decided to type it manually and made a mistake.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `new  ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for pointing out to this stupid mistake.

Comment: It works now. I am used to using Eclipse which is not case sensitive when doing ctrl+space(autocomplete), so when the class didn't show up I typed the name manually and made a mistake.

Comment: Okay great it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt it be `new ByteArrayInputStream`?

All the classes, interfaces, packages, methods and fields of java programming language are given according to java naming convention.

In Standard Java naming conventions Objects and class names should start with uppercase character.